# Printing text with escape chars in terminal (macos)

Tags: macos, terminal, nativescript

I'm getting text like below whenI run the program

`notifyAppStarted@file:///app/tns_modules/tn<\M-b\M^@\M-&>`

I assume it's escape codes.

I'd also like to print a string with an escape code (ascii 27) - that's not working also.

Is there a setting in terminal I need to make - this is macos.

Comment: Could you please show us a Playground sample? Between, I don't think it has anything to do with Terminal, it's all about the console module that prints the text you pass in.

Comment: I'm just doing `console.log("message")`. With the correct escape code the text should change color. E.g. console.log("\x1b[1;31mRED"); should print the message in red. Not happening. I can do the above in terminal with "echo -e "escape code" and that works.

Comment: Oh, you are trying to change the color of logs? I don't think that is possible. It's not your terminal that prints the actual log. The terminal just fetches the log from the native emulator / device, which won't support handling colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the color in colors in nativescript console as it is an implementation of native logs from respective platforms e.g. LogCat for Android.

This console is not supporting colors yet. Feature request is open [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/719).

Comment: ok thanks - I asked because when NS prints console messages - it seems to do it in color.